# search between two dates that are entered manually

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the results between two dates when i enter the dates and click the search button. I have only put one date search so far. here's how it is shown. [image]

this is my **index.php**

```
      <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
        <input  type="text" name="Date" placeholder="Date"> 
        <input  type="text" name="Location" placeholder="Location">
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
      </form>
```

this is where i get the search results. **search.php**

```
<?php

/* showing table after searching for date */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        $Location = $_POST['Location'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name,Location,Date,Category,LabourSupplier,InTime,OutTime,Day,DayRate,Salary,OTHours,OTrate,OTAmount,Allowance2,TotalSalary,Advance,SalaryToHand FROM attendance WHERE Date LIKE '%" . $Date . "%' AND Location LIKE '%" . $Location . "%' ORDER BY location DESC, LabourSupplier ASC", $connection)
        or die("Failed to query database" . mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            print "<tr>";
            print "<td >" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Date'] . "</th>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['LabourSupplier'] . "</td>";
            print "<th >" . $row['InTime'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OutTime'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Day'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['DayRate'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Salary'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTHours'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTrate'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTAmount'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Allowance2'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['TotalSalary'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Advance'] . "</th>";
            print "<th>" . $row['SalaryToHand'] . "</th>";
            print "</tr>";
        }
    }

}
print "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* function annymore use mysqli_* function or PDO. mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Your SQL query is prone to SQL injection

Comment: Just forget about all this PHP stuff; it's irrelevant to your problem and very, very out-of-date. Instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I got what i wanted. I had to change only "index.php"

```
        <input  type="text" name="FDate" placeholder="From Date"> 
        <input  type="text" name="TDate" placeholder="To Date">
```

and "search.php"

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name,Location,Date,Category,...,SalaryToHand FROM attendance WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$_POST["FDate"]."' AND '".$_POST["TDate"]."' AND Location LIKE '%" . $Location . "%' ORDER BY location DESC, Date DESC",$connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE READ THE END OF THIS ANSWER**

Add another date input:

```
<form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
  <input  type="date" name="Date1" placeholder="Date 1"> 
  <input  type="date" name="Date2" placeholder="Date 2"> 
  <input  type="text" name="Location" placeholder="Location">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

And in your PHP script add the new date input value:

```
<?php

/* showing table after searching for date */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
        $Date1 = $_POST['Date1'];
        $Date2 = $_POST['Date2'];
        $Location = $_POST['Location'];

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ID,Name,Location,Date,Category,LabourSupplier,InTime,OutTime,Day,DayRate,Salary,OTHours,OTrate,OTAmount,Allowance2,TotalSalary,Advance,SalaryToHand FROM attendance WHERE Date BETWEEN $Date1 AND $Date2 AND Location LIKE '%" . $Location . "%' ORDER BY location DESC, LabourSupplier ASC")
        or die("Failed to query database" . mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            print "<tr>";
            print "<td >" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Date'] . "</th>";
            print "<td >" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
            print "<td >" . $row['LabourSupplier'] . "</td>";
            print "<th >" . $row['InTime'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OutTime'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Day'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['DayRate'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Salary'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTHours'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTrate'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['OTAmount'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Allowance2'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['TotalSalary'] . "</th>";
            print "<th >" . $row['Advance'] . "</th>";
            print "<th>" . $row['SalaryToHand'] . "</th>";
            print "</tr>";
        }
    }

}
print "</table>";

?>
```

**INPORTANT**

**Please try to use PHP-PDO instead of regular old deprecated MySQL function. Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection and it is highly recommended to change it**

Comment: Wel this may answer the topicstarter question.. answers should not include  deprecated functions like mysql_*

Comment: it is mysqli_query($connection, $query) not mysqli_query($query)

Comment: I've added it at the end like `mysqli_query( $query, $connection)`

Comment: It should be at the beginning. It's the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of single date `<input  type="text" name="Date" placeholder="Date">`, use two date like:

```
<input  type="text" name="from_date" placeholder="Date">
<input  type="text" name="to_date" placeholder="Date">
```

and use it in query like:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN $from_date and $to_date
```

**Note:** But you have to keep in mind the sql injection issue.

Comment: Well this may answer the topic starters question... this advice is prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM attendance
WHERE Date BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);

Comment: You don't need a CAST for date.. this also works `SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-28'`